# Table validation rule error: Unknown function 'Nz' in validation expression or default value on 'TableName'

Tags: ms-access, validationrules

In Microsoft Access, I am trying to enforce table validation to have *one and only one* foreign key filled using table validation rule on Long Integer `...ID` fields:

```
Nz([MeasurementPointID], 0) = 0 Xor Nz([MeterID], 0) = 0
```

But when saving table definition (table name is `Readout`), the following error is displayed:

```
Unknown function 'Nz' in validation expression or default value on 'Readout'
```

and this is correct, because on pressing the `…` button, function `Nz()` is missing from Expression Builder.

How to implement the above requirement without `Nz()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more general rewrite is just use `IIF`, which is available, and is a dropin replacement for `Nz`

`Nz([MeasurementPointID], 0)` becomes `IIF([MeasurementPointID] IS NOT NULL, [MeasurementPointID], 0)`

Generally, casting back and forth to a string will take a large performance hit.

Comment: Hi Erik, a good catch! The confusing point was that `IIf()` similarily to `Nz()`, is not listed  in the Expression Builder. I thought that `Nz()` throws errors because it is not listed and therefore `IIf()` will follow the suit. Obviously, there is a inconsistency there and each function has to better tested even if not listed what is my greatest lesson from this Q/A. Your last sentence is a bit superfluous, because I would definitely prefer `IIf()` if its availability was obvious. Without `IIf()`, there is no other way than casting.

Comment: The difference between `Iif` and `Nz` is that `Nz` is only implemented at the application level, while `Iif` is implemented at the database level. This also means you can't use `Nz` when querying an Access database over ODBC connections, and in some other cases. However, I haven't found a good resource yet on which functions are and aren't implemented at the database level in Access, so I can't point you to more general guidance on what is and isn't allowed in constraints.